# React Native :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug error in Android build

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to build my project, which I was successfully building, but now I get this error

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1
```

I needed to build my project to apply new packages, but while doing it firebase packages gave me error so I upgraded them then here I'm.. I tried %90 of the all suggested solutions in the google none of them worked..

> android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> android/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "Profile.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative57"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
            release {
                if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                    storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }
     }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')

    implementation project(':react-native-sound')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')

    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2641",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.12",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.12",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-typewriter": "^0.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is related migration to `Androidx`, google play service updated to `androidX`

If you are using `real-native-info`, please upgrade. It will solve your problem with **2.1.2**

See [here apply link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503042684)

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56650057/11212074) to this question

> Apply Note: Upgrading `com.google.android.gms` to 17.0.0 will cause many
>   problems.

Comment: Well before I was using 16.0.1, It was giving error so I had to use 17.0.0. Now after updating react-native-device-info I again used 16.0.1 and it didn give error and I could take build! I'm not sure if this solution %100 connected with the problem but it solved.

Comment: @Berke People with those modules had these symptoms when Google was updated. And it's probably the root cause of the error that Google updating.

Comment: Yeah It look like this.. Thank you really, because Its a bit new and detailed problem, hope it will help others as well.