# What can break an android build without code changes?

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play-services

I am working on a `react-native` app that uses [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/). I've setup a CI build on travis with the aim to have reproducible builds, and it has suddenly stopped working, as detailed here:

- [before](https://travis-ci.org/mapswipe/mapswipe/jobs/545759097): 4 days ago, the build works
- [after](https://travis-ci.org/mapswipe/mapswipe/jobs/545759086#L3002): today, the exact same build is broken, failing with the following message:

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

My only reasonable guess is that some dependency has changed, but I don't understand android builds well enough to figure out what has happened or why.

And obviously, how do I prevent such surprises from happening in the future? (in my mind, this build should be perfectly repeatable)

As a side note, when the build fails, it also shows several warnings like:

> WARNING: Conflict with dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for runtime classpath (17.0.0) and compile classpath (16.0.1) differ. This can lead to runtime crashes. To resolve this issue follow advice at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-project-wide-properties. Alternatively, you can try to fix the problem by adding this snippet to /home/travis/build/mapswipe/mapswipe/android/app/build.gradle:
>   dependencies {
>       implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0")
>   }

but following that advice only causes further (different) errors.

Comment: [Your answer is here, this saved my day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648263/android-dependency-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-stats-has-different-ve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is related migration to Androidx, google play service updated to androidX

If you are using `real-native-info`, please upgrade. It will solve your problem with **2.1.2**

See [here apply link](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503024749)

> Note: Upgrading `com.google.android.gms` to 17.0.0 will cause many
>   problems.

Comment: The details of the answer are in this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503045776 Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: @LaurentS It seems that many people have been experiencing this problem since Google was updated. Could you choose an my answer if it was helpful?

Comment: Yes, accepting your answer as it helped me solve my problem. I wrote another answer, just for the record, which actually addresses my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, [this comment on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503045776) provides the answer to my question:

A dependency (`react-native-device-info` in my case) was using the latest version of one of its dependencies instead of a fixed/pinned version. When a new release of google services was released, it caused the build to pull in the new version for `device-info`, thereby causing the conflict with other dependencies that correctly pin the version they need.