# Change to androidX in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

I'm trying to change my `react-native` project to `androidx`.
I want to do it because I got this error suddenly when trying to run my project:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

I was reading some posts about the issue and I tried to add those lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

because when I used stack trace I was getting this error:

```
Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable react native
```

I added this lines to my `local.propeties` file but when I did that I have seen that I need to change all my `node-module` files to use `androidx`

In addition I was trying to update the package `react-native-device-info` to the newest version 2.1.2 but still the same result...

my react native version:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.50.4
```

I'm attaching my files:

**app/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

 buildscript {
   repositories {
     maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }
   dependencies {
     // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
     // quickly to Android tooling updates
     classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
   }
 }
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
 repositories {
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 14
        versionName "2.3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-device-information')
    compile project(':react-native-ble-manager')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker-module')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0' //17.3.1
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-notifications'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
         transitive = true;
    }

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

//com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(50000)

allprojects {
    repositories {
                // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        // maven{
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}

ext {
  compileSdkVersion = 28
  targetSdkVersion = 28
  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
  supportLibVersion = "28.0.0-rc02"
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
  oreoEXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my application for **androidManifest.xml**:

```
  <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
      android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
>
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue for now? I can't run my project suddenly

Comment: anyone has any solution?

Comment: so has happened to me :-/

Comment: @AsifAli did you find any solution? do you know why does it happened?

Comment: not yet @JJ Redikes, I think some internal dependencies are failed to compile with android x .. need to look at each dependency separately

Comment: Many libraries were affected by the new release of google services. For us, it was react-native-push-notification and react-native-device-info. Since you have the first dependency in your app/build.gradle, check this solution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25292#issuecomment-503034120. This solved it for us

Comment: @Vely thank you so much, this is solve my problem!!
I would like to upgrade my RN to 0.59 but I know its complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines in `android/app/build.gradle` fixed it for me (based on [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25292#issuecomment-503034120)).  `react-native-push-notification` has a dependency on androidx that was causing the failure.

```
implementation(project(':react-native-push-notification')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0") {
    force = true
}
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0") {
    force = true
}
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9") {
    force = true
}
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0") {
    force = true
}
```

If you don't have a `react-native-push-notification` dependency already, you can check where your androidx dependency lies with:

`cd android && ./gradlew app:dependencies`

(See [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25292#issuecomment-502998885) for more details on that approach.)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is related migration to `Androidx`, google play service updated to `androidX`

If you are using `real-native-info`, please upgrade. It will solve your problem with **2.1.2**

```
yarn uprade react-native-info@2.1.2
```

See [here apply link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503042684)

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56650057/11212074) to this question

[similar question's second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56649829/11212074) to this question

> Apply Note: Upgrading `com.google.android.gms` to 17.0.0 will cause many
>   problems.

Comment: thank for the answer im using npm, what is the react-native-info and what is the command i should do?
as you see in my gradle files there is no mention to react-native-info...

Comment: @JJRedikes `yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2` and `cd android && gradlew clean`

Comment: do I need to keep the lines of:
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
or delete them?

more than that my com.google.gms version is 4.1.0 and not 17...

Comment: It seems good to delete that part. If you need this syntax, `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=false`

Comment: you cant do one false and the second true.. they have to be the same value

Comment: If so, the deletion does not affect the error. If the module has been updated normally and a clean.

Comment: I'm use `yarn upgrade`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195154/discussion-between-jj-redikes-and-hong-develop).